# How to set terraform AWS region automatically?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am being prompted for the following when I run `terragrunt plan`.
How can I automate this. I am using `terragrunt version 12`.

```
[terragrunt] 2021/07/27 04:17:08 Running command: terraform plan
provider.aws.region
  The region where AWS operations will take place. Examples
  are us-east-1, us-west-2, etc.
```

My `terragrunt.hcl` code:

```
terraform {
  source = "some git repo"
}
```

Comment: What is your TF code? What what `terragrunt` has to do with terraform? Do you have any example to show demonstrating your use-case and the issue?

Comment: @Marcin updated the code, I am using `terragrunt `as a wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings related to where Terraform should be managing objects, including cloud system regions or local service API endpoints, should typically be written down in the provider configuration for the relevant provider, so that they're guaranteed to remain consistent between runs.

For AWS in particular:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Terraform is prompting you for this value because for the AWS provider in particular `region` is an required argument, and so Terraform prompts for it as a more helpful alternative to just returning an error saying that you must set it. However, you can and should set it in the configuration, using a configuration block like I've shown above, so that this configuration will always use a consistent region each time you apply it.

Note that although providers often also allow specifying authentication-related settings in the configuration for pragmatic reasons, you should typically *not* set anything that is related to who is running Terraform in the configuration, because you'll probably have many different people running Terraform against this configuration over time. Everyone will typically need to be working against the same region, but it's unlikely that everyone will share the same credentials, and so it's better to leave the credentials unconfigured in Terraform and have the AWS provider load them in [the usual ways that AWS tools load credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html), such as the `~/.aws/credentials` file.